# Does ready event fire when page-turn

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a book, and use `jQuery` to change pages etc.
At the top I have an `$(document).ready(function()` that does different stuff when the page is loaded.

On the GUI page I got a "change page" button, and when this is pushed, the function `turnPage()` is called. This method contain some code pluss this:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#device"+window.device, {
    transition: "slide",
    reverse: false,
    changeHash: true
});
```

My question is, when `turnPage()` is called, is also `$(document).ready(function()` called?
(Yes, I am new to this)

Comment: See the update answer. I found the docs of the plugin.

Comment: You can't edit your question to a different question because you're prevented by the site asking new question. I rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DOM ready event is an event that fires when the DOM is fully loaded except of images (`<img>`).

The event fires **once** for each page load. So:

- If the `turn page()` function makes a redirect, the answer is **Yes**.
- If the `turn page()` function  only gets data with `ajax` request, the answer is **No**.

---

**Important Update:**
I found this in the official plugin [website](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) :

> **Important: Use pageInit(), not $(document).ready()**
>
> The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the $(document).ready() function so everything will execute as soon as the DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event.
> ...
> ...

So `turn page` does an `ajax` request, so the final answer is  **No**.

What is the ready event:

> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets such as images have been completely received. In most cases, the script can be run as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed. The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code. When using scripts that rely on the value of CSS style properties, it's important to reference external.

Comment: thanks, I made some edit questions to the first post I made. Had to do it like this because I was not allowed to post anyting before 8hours after my first post.

Comment: @TorK. You can't edit your question to a different question because you're prevented by the site asking new question. I rolled back your edit.